# SignalR authentication failed when passing "Bearer" through query string

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr.client, bearer-token

I'd like to enable authentication in SignalR while the server was hosted in ASP.NET WebAPI which I'm using OAuth Bearer authrntication and the client is AngularJS.

On client side I originally pass the Bearer token through HTTP header and it works well with the WebAPI. But since SignalR JavsScript doesn't support adding HTTP headers in `connection` (it's because WebSocket doesn't support specifying HTTP headers) I need to pass the Bearer token through query string by using the code like `self.connection.qs = { Bearer: 'xxxxxx' };`

The problem is on the WebAPI side my SignalR always returned 401 Unauthorized.

Below is what I did on the WebAPI side.

1, I specified `OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.Provider` to `QueryStringEnabledOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider`, which is a class I created inherited from `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider` that can retrieve Bearer token from query string. Code as below.

```
    public class QueryStringEnabledOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private readonly string _name;

        public QueryStringEnabledOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
            : this(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType)
        {
        }

        public QueryStringEnabledOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
        {
            // try to read token from base class (header) if possible
            base.RequestToken(context).Wait();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Token))
            {
                // try to read token from query string
                var token = context.Request.Query.Get(_name);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                {
                    context.Token = token;
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(null);
        }
    }
```

And registered it as below while WebAPI was started.

```
            var options = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AuthenticationType = AuthenticationType,
                Provider = new QueryStringEnabledOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = _accessTokenFormat,
            };
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(options);
```

2, In SignalR part I created an authorize attribute as below. Nothing changed just to be used to add break point.

```
    public class BearerAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
        {
            return base.AuthorizeHubConnection(hubDescriptor, request);
        }

        public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
        {
            return base.AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(hubIncomingInvokerContext, appliesToMethod);
        }
    }
```

And registered it when WebAPI started as well.

```
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
                {
                    // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                    // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                    // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                    // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                    {
                        // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                        // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                        // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                        // EnableJSONP = true
                        EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
                    };
                    // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                    // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                    // path.
                    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
                    // Require authentication for all hubs
                    var authorizer = new BearerAuthorizeAttribute();
                    var module = new AuthorizeModule(authorizer, authorizer);
                    GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(module);
                });
```

I found, when SignalR connected my `QueryStringEnabledOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider.RequestToken` was invoked and it retrieved Bearer token successfully. But then when SignalR `BearerAuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeHubConnection` was invoked the parameter `request.User` still not authenticated. So it returned 401.

Can anyone give me some ideas on what's wrong I did, thanks.

Comment: you don't have to inherit from OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider just for specifying a custom RequestToken behavior.
you can set the OnRequestToken delegate of your OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider instance.

Comment: I have answered this question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657296/signalr-authentication-with-webapi-bearer-token/31105356#31105356

Answer (score 3):

I'm using headers, this is how I solved it

```
var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
var token = authData.token;
$.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = { Authorization: "Bearer " + token };
```

Hope it helps

Comment: setting headers will use 'longPolling' transport. 'webSockets' transport doesn't support headers.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by unprotect the Bearer token from query string in my AuthorizeAttribute, and set the user principal into a new ServerRequest. For detailed information please check http://blog.shaunxu.me/archive/2014/05/27/set-context-user-principal-for-customized-authentication-in-signalr.aspx

This might not be the best solution but it worked.

Comment: transporting token from query string is a security issue , can be viewed, logged etc.

Comment: Shaun Xu,
I tried to comment on http://blog.shaunxu.me/archive/2014/05/27/set-context-user-principal-for-customized-authentication-in-signalr.aspx 

but displaying captchais broken there, no way to post.